# "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'alter'" when adding foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have these tables :

```
Employee(Ename, SSN, Bdate, Address, Dnumber)
Department ( Dname,Dno,Dmgr_SSN(
Project(Pname, Pnumber, Plocation, Dnum)
WorksON(SSN,Pnumber,Hours)
```

When I try to use `ALTER`:

```
alter  table  Employee 
add foreign key (Dnumber)
 REFERENCES Department (Dno);
```

I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'alter'.

Note : I write this query under the definition of tables query

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx), including the examples?

Comment: Just to ask the obvious. Are you executing the "create table" and the "alter table" one shot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [**documentation** on the `ALTER TABLE` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) would have easily shown you that this is the syntax to use:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee 
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Employee_Department
  FOREIGN KEY(Dnumber) REFERENCES dbo.Department(Dno);
```